# Generated Navbar in Phalcon

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

Hi im gonna get straight into it. this is what i want:

- Category A

  - item 1
  - item 2
- Category B

  - item 1
  - item 2

This is what i got:

- Category A

  - Item 1
- Category A

  - Item 2
- Category B

  - Item 1
- Category B

  - Item 2

My code

Controller

```
$_mongo = new MongoClient();
$_mongo->selectDB("data");
$articles = $_mongo->selectDB("data")->selectCollection("articles");
$articlelist = $articles->find();
$articlelist->sort(array('category' => 1));
    if($articlelist->count() > 0){
        foreach($articlelist as $article){

        }
}
$this->view->setVar('articlelist', $articlelist);
```

NavBar Partial

```
<nav class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
        <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                {% for article in articlelist %}
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{article['_id']}}">{{article['category']}}</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse{{article['_id']}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{article['uri']}}">{{article['title']}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Src Data:

```
$post = array(
            'date_created'  => new MongoDate(),
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'date' => date("d/m/y h:i:sa"),
            'category' => $_POST['category'],
            'uri' => $category . "/" . $string, //uri generated by category and title
            'content' => $_POST['content']
            );
            $posts->save($post);
```

My thinking was that I could just do `$articles->find('category')` then just loop through that separately, but apparently that can't be done in a noSQL like mongo.  I'm kind of stumped with this how would, what would be the simplest way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't be two hard to work out. You need a list of items that has child items. For each item to then also need to loop the children.  Note that your template logic is wrong because you are not looping twice. But it depends on what your source data looks like. So you need to show us that as well.

Comment: @Neil Updated. So like `$parentcat = ??` then `if ($parentcat == $category){ foreach($articlelist as $article){ }}`

Comment: Can you show us example of `articlelist` structure?

Comment: @yergo You mean the structure of the database right, if so I posted it above.

Comment: @Chaosjosh no i ment value of `$articlelist` during `$this->view->setVar('articlelist', $articlelist);`

Comment: @yergo well `$articlelist = $articles->find()` which would be an array of all articles in the collection structured in the way posted above.

Comment: @Chaosjosh well maybe it's my bad idea to comment from work, wishing for raw php array structure to not think too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. PHP Example

Simple presentation of logic:

```
$a = [
    ['category' => 'a', 'title' => 'Title 1'],
    ['category' => 'a', 'title' => 'Title 2'],
    ['category' => 'b', 'title' => 'Title 1'],
    ['category' => 'b', 'title' => 'Title 2'],
];

$currentCat = null;
foreach ($a as $article) {
    if ($currentCat != $article['category']) {
        print("\t" . $article['category'] . PHP_EOL);
        $currentCat = $article['category'];
    }
    print("\t\t" . $article['title'] . PHP_EOL);
}
```

in case of having structure so flat, but sorted properly, you have to remember last category you are in and draw header on its change.

## 2. Volt Example

```
{% set currentCat = null %}
{% for article in articlelist %}

    {% if article['category'] != currentCat %}
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{ article['_id'] }}">{{ article['category'] }}</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        {% set currentCat = article['category'] %}
    {% endif %}

    <div id="collapse{{article['_id']}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{article['uri']}}">{{article['title']}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

its a logic-copy of previous PHP example, just translated to Volt with your provided html. Should work fine, but not tested. What I'm doing there is as previously, remembering last category and if it has hanged, drawing header for it.

Comment: thankyou, I was able to achieve the result with the PHP example, the Volt example is a little more difficult since i'm new to phalcon. Should be `{% if article['category'] != currentCat %}` since its an array rather than an object.  that being said idk what `category.currentCat` would translate to... `currentCat['category']` maybe?